# Depth error in 2D image with OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to compute the Canny Edges in an image (ndarray) using OpenCV with Python.

```
slice1 = slices[15,:,:]
slice1 = slice1[40:80,60:100]
print slice1.shape
print slice1.dtype
slicecanny = cv2.Canny(slice1, 1, 100)
```

Output:

```
(40, 40)
float64
...
error: /Users/jmerkow/code/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/imgproc/src/canny.cpp:49: 
error: (-215) src.depth() == CV_8U in function Canny
```

For some reason I get the above error.  Any ideas why?

Comment: you may need to convert the data type to float (CV_32F) since canny do gaussian filtering which (if OpenCV use Filter2D) requires float data input.

Comment: I tried converting to float32 and integers, not luck.  I also tried:      slice2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(slice1,(5,5),1)
    slicecanny = cv2.Canny(slice2,1,100)

Comment: In your error output: error: (-215) src.depth() == CV_8U in function Canny. May be I was complete in wrong direction. Have you try to convert to CV_8U as the input (not integer, since integer is not UInt8).

Comment: Yes, I just tried that, same error.  The function works when I read an image from file, i.e. slice1 = cv.imread('../images/3.jpg',0). Could it have something to do with obtaining the 'slice' from a 3D voxel set?  Maybe some memory/pointer thing in python?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Slice1 will need to be casted or created as a uint8. CV_8U is just an alias for the datatype uint8.

```
import numpy as np
slice1Copy = np.uint8(slice1)
slicecanny = cv2.Canny(slice1Copy,1,100)
```

Comment: but the pixel values are in float 0-1 range. uint loses that data.

Comment: @SaleemAhmed in the OP the depth buffer is CV_8U which means single channel 8 bit unsigned int. If you're using pixels, identify the type of array data CV_*, then use the appropriate np conversion function e.g. np.ufloat32()

see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html for more

Answer (score 9):

In order to avoid losing precision while changing the data type to uint8, you can first adapt the scale to the 255 format just doing:

```
(image*255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Here I'm considering that image is a numpy array and np stand for numpy. I hope it can help someone!

Comment: You can use the edit button to improve your answer. Comments don't tend to stick around, so your addition might get lost over time.

Comment: Thanks Luuklag, I'm not very used to introduce comments!

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this error by saving slice1 to a file and then reading it

```
from scipy import ndimage, misc
misc.imsave('fileName.jpg', slice1)
image = ndimage.imread('fileName.jpg',0)
slicecanny = cv2.Canny(image,1,100)
```

This is not the most elegant solution, but it solved the problem for me

Comment: this works because reading from a file gives you a 0-255 uint8 image, but its not efficient. Just convert the image to 0-255 range (multiply by 255) and use slice1.astype(np.uint8)