# i want to implement image processing but it shows some error

Tags: python

```
if not len(blurred.shape) == 2:
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
            else:
                gray = blurred
            edge = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150)  

        circles = AHTforCircles(edge,center_threhold_factor=params[i]['center_threhold_factor'],score_threhold=params[i]['score_threhold'],min_center_dist=params[i]['min_center_dist'],minRad=params[i]['minRad'],
                                maxRad=params[i]['maxRad'],center_axis_scale=params[i]['center_axis_scale'],radius_scale=params[i]['radius_scale'],
                                halfWindow=params[i]['halfWindow'],max_circle_num=params[i]['max_circle_num'])
        final_img = drawCircles(circles,blurred)

        plt.imshow(final_img)
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.show()


edge = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150)
```

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\canny.cpp:829:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) _src.depth() == CV_8U in function
>   'cv::Canny'

Comment: `cv::Canny` requires uint8 data type. A question with the same error was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103933/depth-error-in-2d-image-with-opencv-python).

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpfully to receive some description of your problem. What you are trying to do etc. When problem occurs. You know help us little bit before we can help you:)

Answer (score 0):

An input image to the `cv2.Canny()` function has the wrong data type. It needs to be unsigned 8-bit integers (what OpenCV calls `CV_8U`), and you have something else (we can't see what from your code).

Change to `cv2.Canny(gray.astype('uint8'))` and that particular problem should go away.

Note though, that you might want to think about what data type your images have, and do this conversion somewhere else.